# Dynamic SQL string error in selecting statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic sql statement and I believe it will work the problem I have is when I create the procedure the select statement has a problem with ''Quote''.

Here is my procedure.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetPanelData(@FirstYear int = null, @SecondYear int = null, @ThirdYear int = null, @CompanySelected int = null)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ParameterDefinition NVARCHAR(4000);

SELECT @ParameterDefinition = '@Year1 int,
                               @Year2 int,
                               @Year3 int,
                               @companyID int';

SELECT @SQL = N'
    SELECT FirstColumn.Type, 
            FirstColumn.YearPanelCount,
            SecondColumn.YearPanelCount

    FROM
     (SELECT ''Quote'' AS Type, sum(mdl.Panel) AS YearPanelCount
     FROM Model mdl, Quote QT, Quote_Line_Items QLT, Products Prd
     WHERE QT.QuoteID = QLT.QuoteID AND
      QLT.ProductID = Prd.ProductID AND
      Prd.ModelID = mdl.ModelID AND
      DATEPART(YYYY, QT.Quote_Date) = @Year1 AND
      Prd.CompanyID = @companyID) AS FirstColumn
';

IF @SecondYear IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'
    inner join(
    SELECT ''Quote'' AS Type, sum(mdl.Panel) AS YearPanelCount
    FROM Model mdl, Quote QT, Quote_Line_Items QLT, Products Prd
    WHERE QT.QuoteID = QLT.QuoteID AND
      QLT.ProductID = Prd.ProductID AND
      Prd.ModelID = mdl.ModelID AND
      DATEPART(YYYY, QT.Quote_Date) = @Year2 AND
      Prd.CompanyID = @companyID) AS SecondColumn
    on FirstColumn.Type = SecondColumn.Type
';

IF @ThirdYear IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'
    inner join(
    (SELECT ''Quote'' AS Type, sum(mdl.Panel) AS YearPanelCount
    FROM Model mdl, Quote QT, Quote_Line_Items QLT, Products Prd
    WHERE QT.QuoteID = QLT.QuoteID AND
      QLT.ProductID = Prd.ProductID AND
      Prd.ModelID = mdl.ModelID AND
      DATEPART(YYYY, QT.Quote_Date) = @Year3 AND
      Prd.CompanyID = @companyID)) AS ThirdColumn
    on FirstColumn.Type = ThirdColumn.Type
    ';

EXEC sp_executeSQL  @SQL, 
    @ParameterDefinition, 
    @Year1 = @FirstYear, 
    @Year2 = @SecondYear, 
    @Year3 = @ThirdYear,
    @CompanyID = @CompanySelected;
GO

EXEC GetPanelData @FirstYear = 2012, @SecondYear = 2013, @CompanySelected = '1';
```

Does anyone know why I get this error when I run it. 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near 'Quote'.

When I run the query SELECT 'Quote', sum(mdl.Panel) it works but for some reason in this case it cannot.

Comment: Show the actual generated quote. `Line 27` is useless without seeing what the end-product is.

Comment: show the value of @SQL before this line EXEC sp_executeSQL

Comment: Literally I just want it to show up as 
| TYPE | YearPanelCount |
| Quote | 1029(count ex.)  |

is it not possible to just select a static value as first selection?

Comment: Has that very first `(` a corresponding `)`?

Comment: rene that was a good spot but now it is saying that Quote is an invalid column name. Which doesn't make sense to me because it works in a single select statement and the column name should be Type

Comment: this is very bad debugging approach, just watch the code only, why not you include the value of @sql before execution using PRINT statement? thats give the exact place where the error is

Comment: I updated my code and fixed the problem. I was using FirstColumn.Quote = SecondColumn.Quote when it needed to be .Type Thanks for suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues. The first is that the closing quote for your entire query is conditioned on the @ThirdYear parameter, which is null on your execution, leaving you with an unclosed parenthesis. The first open parenthesis seems unnecessary, so I would change

```
SELECT @SQL = N'
(SELECT FirstColumn.Type,...
```

to

```
SELECT @SQL = N'
SELECT FirstColumn.Type,...
```

If you want your query to be encased in parenthesis, you should move the closed parenthesis to a final `set` after the parameterized sets:

```
SET @SQL = @SQL + ')'
```

The second issue I see, which I think will throw another error once you fix the first issue, is that you are attempting to join on column names `Quote` which do not exist. Perhaps you meant to join on column name `Type`?

Comment: Thank you for the input I figured out the problem I already updated my code earlier I didn't see that you had commented but these were the two solutions.

Comment: No problem, any time.